# .htaccess rewrite dynamic url problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there is lots of rewrite topic but i coulndt get it. So I try to rewrite url with htaccess. But I don't know very well about rewrite rule so i want your helps.

rewrite index.php to root(it works).

```
www.example.com/index.php ---> www.example.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

After index.php to root rewrite my dynamic url change from this

```
https://example.com/index.php?baslik=dynamic-slug-url
```

to this

```
https://example.com/?baslik=dynamic-slug-url
```

Php codes(fetch etc.) work fine and no problem. But I want to change into this(I tried dynamic url rewrite generator but no result):

```
https://example.com/dynamic-slug-url
```

After the above things, I want to change something else. From this;

```
https://example.com/specificfile.php?target=dynamicid
```

to this

```
https://example.com/dynamicid
```

When it became upper thing,

```
https://example.com/specificfile.php?target=dynamicid&baslik=dynamic-slug-url
```

Will be

```
https://example.com/dynamicid&baslik=dynamic-slug-url
```

But I want like this

```
https://example.com/dynamicid/dynamic-slug-url
```

I hope i told my problem and other things clear. I tried lost of url rewrite generator but couldnt get no result. Thank you for your answer and good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that problem as a little exercise for myself and this is what I came up with:

```
# 1) from https://example.com/index.php?baslik=dynamic-slug-url
#      to https://example.com/dynamic-slug-url
#     and
# 2) from https://example.com/specificfile.php?target=dynamicid
#      to https://example.com/dynamicid
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(baslik|target)=([^/.&]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)(index|specificfile)\.(php|html?)$ https://example.com/%2? [R=301,L]

# 3) from https://example.com/specificfile.php?target=dynamicid&baslik=dynamic-slug-url
#      to https://example.com/dynamicid/dynamic-slug-url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^target=([^/.&]+)&baslik=([^/.&]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)(index|specificfile)\.(php|html?)$ https://example.com/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

[Demo on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=5dba3b7b-d3bf-5c9f-ac26-42fd0d86fe04)

Comment: It is perfectly rewrite the url but i get 404 error when its rewrite the url. Should i do something in php file? What i know is https://example.com/dynamic-slug-url and https://example.com/index.php?baslik=dynamic-slug-url goes same php but users see friendly one. Am i wrong?

Comment: @BlackySen Sorry, I'd like to help but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I get 404 error. looks like rewrite normal but network console says 404 https://prnt.sc/s9q543